# How to handle a large amount of geometry data in a WPF drawing?

Tags: c#, wpf, vector-graphics

I am drawing some items to a `DrawingGroup` in a WPF UI I am experimenting with, the code looks a little like this:

```
foreach( var path in allRoads ) 
{
    var wpfPen = new Pen(brush, penSize);
    GeometryDrawing geometry = new GeometryDrawing();
    geometry.Pen = wpfPen;
    geometry.Geometry = GetPathGeometry(path);
    drawingGroup.Children.Add(geometry);
}
```

This is called repeatedly as I draw in the various geometry items I am rendering ( I am adding them to the `DrawingGroup` then asking the `DrawingContext` to draw it afterwards ) but it gets into trouble and crashes out with the following message:

> The thread 0x3228 has exited with code 0 (0x0). Exception thrown:
>   'System.OverflowException' in PresentationCore.dll An unhandled
>   exception of type 'System.OverflowException' occurred in
>   PresentationCore.dll The image data generated an overflow during
>   processing.

The crash seems to be happening just short of the 38000th geometry item ( all of them mult-point paths, some probably quite long as this is GIS data ) being added to the `DrawingGroup.Children` collection.

I'm guessing that this is probably pushing the system past what it is designed for - is there a better way to handle this within WPF? Can it deal with a lot of geometry data and if not, whereabouts are the limits?

Comment: Only draw those geometries that are actually visible?

Comment: @Clemens is on the right path. I'm guessing you are drawing some kind of graph, so implement a sliding window approach so you are only drawing the portion of the graph that's actually on screen.

Comment: @Clemens I'm drawing a map ( GIS data )  that is zoomed out quite a long way, so the vector data I am looking at here is every road over a ~100 square mile densely populated area. If the map is zoomed out, which it needs to be sometimes, all of those points are in view. Of course some of them are indistinguishable zoomed out, so it might be possible to test for collisions.

Comment: You should implement a means of reducing the amount of geometries that are drawn when you zoom out. The data should have kind of minimum map scale where it is visible. A forest path should not be visible at scales larger than e.g. 1:10000, while a highway might still be visible when you look at a whole country.

Comment: @Clemens I don't know if the data exists, but one way or another I can probably cull some of it on wider views. Are there any guidelines for how much geometry WPF can be asked to draw before it starts falling over?

Comment: That is the wrong question. Your application should simply draw as less data as possible (but enough to create sensible output of course). Note that there are also useful algorithms to reduce the number of points in a polyline, e.g. Douglas-Ramer-Peucker.

Comment: You should implement a way of handling multiple levels of detail(LOD). When you zoom out you don't need details, so you can "merge" data into simpler shapes. The more you zoom out the less detail you see.

Comment: Are there any tools to facilitate this built in to WPF or widely used? I haven't worked with it much before, hence running into these problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Non-parametric Ramer-Douglas-Peucker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) algorithm to simplify the collection of points before trying to render them.  This would keep the same basic shape, but greatly reduce the detail (detail that won't even be visible at the zoom levels you are talking about).

Pseudo-code from Wikipedia:

```
function DouglasPeucker(PointList[], epsilon)
    // Find the point with the maximum distance
    dmax = 0
    index = 0
    end = length(PointList)
    for i = 2 to ( end - 1) {
        d = perpendicularDistance(PointList[i], Line(PointList[1], PointList[end])) 
        if ( d > dmax ) {
            index = i
            dmax = d
        }
    }
    // If max distance is greater than epsilon, recursively simplify
    if ( dmax > epsilon ) {
        // Recursive call
        recResults1[] = DouglasPeucker(PointList[1...index], epsilon)
        recResults2[] = DouglasPeucker(PointList[index...end], epsilon)

        // Build the result list
        ResultList[] = {recResults1[1...length(recResults1)-1], recResults2[1...length(recResults2)]}
    } else {
        ResultList[] = {PointList[1], PointList[end]}
    }
    // Return the result
    return ResultList[]
end
```

Here is a link to a [C# implementation](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18936/A-Csharp-Implementation-of-Douglas-Peucker-Line-Ap).

You could dynamically adjust the `epsilon` value based on the zoom level to keep things looking correct no matter how close or far you are zoomed.

Comment: Addendum: If anyone else is looking to do this and happens to be using PostGIS ( plausibly other geometry data stores ) there are some handy functions in the datastore to manage simplifying geometry, which saves a bit of implementation.